# What is the whitish bump on fishes head?

Tags: skin-condition, goldfish

[image]

There’s a weird bump on my gold fishes face. I don’t know if it’s a parasite or from him bumping his head on the ride home

Comment: can you please add the result of your latest water test PH-Ammonia-Nitrite,is your tank properly cycled? you can read about how to cycle your tank here:https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm

Comment: This looks like it might be one of those typical round fish glasses. If yes, then the glass is simply too small for your fish (they are *always* too small and should be considered abusive for any fish). Please [read more about aquarium size requirements here](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/10861/12501).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White patch and spot on my goldfish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29075/white-patch-and-spot-on-my-goldfish)