# What happened to my betta fish?

Tags: aquarium, fish, betta, death

I recently bought a platnium betta male who just passed. I had him in a tank with 2 mollies and a female betta, but they all seemed to get along perfectly. I do believe that I should've taken the female out, that was my stupidity. But my grandma got my attention to the betta's eyes. One was brighter than the other. Today, we noticed that his fins seemed to be torn up, but we never saw anybody hurting him because like I said, they all seemed to get along perfectly. The male molly was the only one who was ever around the betta 95% of the time, but I do think the female betta tore up his fins when we weren't paying attention. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the size of your tank, water conditions?

Comment: Knowing parameters will help, but my initial guess is he was attacked. Bettas (generally) should not have tank mates; they will fight.

Comment: The tank is a 10 gallon. I was told by one person that mollies and bettas are fine together, but today another person said you shouldn't put them together. I'm unsure of the water conditions but I do have a filter and the water is a good temperature, as well as being clean

Comment: @CatsAreFriends If you have a fish tank you should either have a water test kit or be able to test your water at a local pet shop regularily. Fish excretements release toxic chemicals into the water. There is no way to know how much chemicals are in the water without testing for it. In addition to your Betta being attacked, the number of fish could have been too much for the filter (and beneficial bacteria) and toxic chemicals could have added up. For more information read about the [nitrogen cycle](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/215/12501)

Comment: I always had a male betta together with (usually) red mollies and other "calm" tropical fish (alongside bottom dwellers like ancistrus), and I never had aggressiveness problems. So it might be that: 1) your fish was sick for some reason 2) the water parameters are sub-optimal.

Comment: @Gwendolyn: maybe you want to say that **male** bettas should not be with other **male** bettas? Because betta girls are not aggressive, and can share an aquarium with anyone. And even male bettas usually share aquariums with other fish - as long as there is only one betta male per aquarium.

Comment: @CatsAreFriends Bettas are also known as Siamese Fighting Fish, that should be your first hint...

Answer (score 0):

Bettas aren't meant to be in the same tank together; males together will fight, though based on my research females together won't. I think the chances of one of them just dying is slim. It's possible that the male attacked the female and you didn't notice, and then the female "got revenge," but that's just a theory.

Comment: Then how did it raise to the top? :) I did not look at the dates. The problem is that I am not sure how to read the answer to make sense. That is why I do not know how to split it and improve it.

Comment: questions without upvoted/selected answers get bumped periodically