# Is my guppy healthy? Its colour is weird

Tags: health, aquarium, guppies, anatomy, new-pets

I just bought a male and female guppy, and the male guppy is really small, probably a month or two old. This is my first time getting a fish. The male guppy seems to have a black spot near his head. Can someone please tell me if it's healthy? The tail side has blue colour at some places only and it's greyish blackish near the head. Please help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Has there been a change to its coloring since you purchased it? How long ago did you buy these fish? Where did you get them?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Only some hint: female guppies often will be stressed by the attention of male guppies. For the females it would be a good thing to get rest, while the male gives the attention to a second or third female. So if possible, buy one or two more females :)

Comment: It just came yesterday and it came like this only

Comment: If this is your first fish, please read [How does one effectively “cycle” an aquarium?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/215/12501). It's very important to know about the nitrogen cycle, because it could kill your fish within the next days or weeks, but pet stores often don't tell customers about it so they can sell more fish after the first ones are dead.

Comment: @Elmy Agreeing with you, I suggest that anyone who does end up getting a fish, act the fish store about it.

Comment: Help I have the same problem and the black spot only comes when I turned the lights on for my male guppies can someone please tell me if it's ok?

Answer (score 4):

I *assume* you mean the weird color of the torso of the guppy.

It looks so weird because it's actually **transparent** and you can see the organs and the spine inside the body. Here's an example of 2 completely healthy guppies:

[image]
*image source: [Phys.org](https://phys.org/news/2020-03-guppies-brothers-sex.html)*

The **lower** fish is completely transparent. You can see the spine and the silver and brown things in the stomach are the inner organs. Depending on the light, they can look silver, grey, brown or reflecting the color of the light.

The **upper** fish has partially pigmented skin. You can still see some features of the inside of the body, but you also see blue, yellow and black features that are only on the skin.

Here's another example:

[image]
*image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guppy)*

The **left** fish is mostly transparent and the colorful spot you see on its stomach is the inner organs that can be seen through the skin.

In your picture it looks like the back half of the body and the fin are strongly pigmented, but the front half is partly or completely transparent. That's why it looks so different.

Comment: I rarely see "fish answers" from you, this is lovely ^.^ oh, to be honest, the lower fish in the first photo is not really completely transparent, please search photos of "glass catfish" for comparison - I still kind of cannot fully believe this fish even exists :D

Comment: @lila Hmm, maybe "translucent" would have been a better term.