# Beginner level community fish tank

Tags: aquarium, fish, community-aquarium

I am planning to set up a 40 gallon(breeder) fish tank to house easy beginner level fishes. I want to go with small fishes. Below are the max combination i came up after researching.

- 6 - neon tetra
- 2 - dwarf gourami
- 6 - Boraras brigittae
- 6 - Harlequin Rasboras
- 6 - Zebra Danios
- 6 - Chili Rasboras
- 6 - Corydoras Catfish
- 5 - Cherry Shrimp
- 2 - Nerite Snails

Someone kindly suggest whether it is practical or not or what can be done better. I want to start with **neon tetra** mostly and the tank setup will be evolved around that. i will not add all this at one go. But this is my plan on the long run.

Comment: The first thing you should know is [how to cycle your tank](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/215/12501). It's the big mistake most beginners do and only few pet shops teach about. Also that sounds like *a lot* of fish for a single tank. Please keep in mind that you're dealing with living creatures that like to reproduce.

Comment: @Elmy that was helpful. It changed my presepctive. I would also like to know about the maintenance process too. If you have any resources for that would be helpful. As I said I will add fish gradually. The above described numbers are maxed and probably will never reach. Also i expected that without breeder tank they wouldn't breed.